# How to get the props value from the loading.tsx in Next JS 13?

Tags: next.js, loading, next.js13

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHoEu.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/84tXq.png)
same result (undefined) when use the fetch data length and default number
right now when I pass the props value from the suspense in character page , it will return undefined. is there any solution for this issue ? Thanks

the items from the loading props is suppose to be 8

Comment: I think fetching data somehow got an error and was not handled. item looking value from the inside component if it's not found then it goes to the parent component fetching the data then it renders with the passed data.

Comment: @GolamrabbiAzad for me i do have the data after the loading is finish so i think the fetch process id not error because i got the data back but i just want to pass the props to the loading in suspense because i can get the item if i put it as a component outside the suspend.

Comment: Alright, fallback works if you pass the props to the loading component from the outside initially it is undefined because it should load as fast as possible. After fetching data completed it then passed the props available to the loading component.

if the item props suppose to be 8 then it should be defined as the default value. I don't see any other way to work around props to the fallback component.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77426639/edit) your question to include your source code as a working [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be tested by others to provide an answer faster. [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.